# Flutter APK size it's greater than 150mb

Tags: flutter

i'm having some problems while compiling my flutter app for Android.. I've only 3 assets and a couple packages added, but when I try to compile, I got this:

`√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (158.3MB).`

Any idea?

**Flutter build log (running flutter build apk)**

```
PS C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Fictix\\Don't Touch This\\app\\dtt_app\> flutter build apk  
Building with sound null safety
```

Comment: Try to build release apk and compare the difference

Comment: Try flutter build apk --release. Also, do you have google_ml_kit in your packages?

Comment: @aoiTenshi, Yes i have google_ml_kit in the package.

Comment: As I heard -I did not try- but google_ml_kit is a big package. Maybe you can try to use specific packages like object detecting or text recognition.

Comment: In versions 0.7.3 and earlier all features were included in a single plugin, but a lot of developers started to get issues with the size of their apps, because even though they only needed a single feature, the plugin included all the resources for the rest of the features, that increased the size of the app significantly. This is what they say in official page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try clearing the cache via terminal.

```
flutter clean
```

This command will delete few temporary folders, specially **"build/", ".dart_tools/" and ".packages/".**

You can also run the following code from the terminal before the build phase of your application.

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
```

Of course, it is not a 100% method, but it can work in reducing your application size.

You can follow the steps below to clear it by Android Studio.

> Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean

Make your app with no sound null safety

From Terminal Run This Command

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

or

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

If your problem still persists

1. // @2.9 in the top remove the parameter from Const app_name();
2. Run --no-sound-null-safety from terminal
3. Edit your Configure File and write in Additional run args:- --no-sound-null-safety